# Сравнение нескольких матриц на Python с выводом матрицы совпадающих элементов

Tags: python, матрицы

Нужно сравнить в Пайтоне несколько матриц равной размерности, и вывести после сравнения матрицу, где в случае наличия во всех сравниваемых матрицах одинаковых элементов в одних и тех же местах тоже будет стоять этот элемент.
Разумеется, итоговая матрица имеет тот же размер что и сравниваемые исходные. Там где в сравниваемых матрицах нет общего элемента должны стоять произвольные символы.

Этот код работает не вполне точно.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from random import randint
import numpy as nm

def matrix_generator(Q, N):
    """Function generates Q matrix with size NxN and pack them into list """

    matrix_list = list()
    for i in range(Q):
        matrix_list.append([])
    for matrix in matrix_list:
        for j in range(N):
            matrix.append([])
    for matrix in matrix_list:
        for line in matrix:
            for k in range(N):
                line.append(randint(0, 9))

    print("Matrix list is: ", matrix_list, "\n")
    return matrix_list


arrays = matrix_generator(3, 3)
result = deepcopy(arrays[0])

for i in range(len(result)):
    for j in range(len(result[i])):
        result[i][j] = "x"


first = arrays[0]
print("First matrix is: ", first, "\n")
# arrays.remove(arrays[0])


for array in arrays:
    # print("Current analyzing array is: ", array)
    for line in array:
        k = array.index(line)
        for item in line:
            l = line.index(item)
            # print(first[k][l], array[k][l])
            if first[k][l] == array[k][l]:
                result[k][l] = first[k][l]
                # print("MATCH!")
            else:
                result[k][l] = "x"


print("Result of compare is", result)
```

Comment: *Этот код работает не вполне точно* — опишите, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit]). в чём именно заключается «неточность»: пример входных данных, ожидаемый результат, получаемый результат.

Comment: [1, 2 ,4][5, 7, 9][6, 7, 5]
[1, 4, 7][4, 7, 0][0, 1, 3]
[1, 4, 3][1, 7, 0][1, 4, 9]

После сранения надо получить матрицу:

[1, _, _][_, 7, _][_, _, _]

Символы что есть во всех исходных матрицах на одних и тех же местах попадают в итоговую матрицу. Остальное мимо. Вот так должна работать программа.

Answer (score 1):

проблема вероятнее всего здесь

```
l = line.index(item)
```

это вернёт индек **первого** встречного элемента, поэтому лучше использовать `range`

```
for array in arrays:
    # print("Current analyzing array is: ", array)
    for k in range(len(array)):
        line = array[k]
        for l in range(len(line)):
            item = line[l]
            # print(first[k][l], array[k][l])
            if first[k][l] == array[k][l]:
                result[k][l] = first[k][l]
                # print("MATCH!")
            else:
                result[k][l] = "x"


print("Result of compare is", result)
```

либо используйте функцию `enumerate`

```
for array in arrays:
    # print("Current analyzing array is: ", array)
    for k, line in enumerate(array):
        for l, item in enumerate(line):
            # print(first[k][l], array[k][l])
            if first[k][l] == array[k][l]:
                result[k][l] = first[k][l]
                # print("MATCH!")
            else:
                result[k][l] = "x"


print("Result of compare is", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в цикле сравнения (если честно, я не особо разобрался/разбирался в ней, но, как сказали выше, сколее всего ошибка из-за `.index()`), но вот вполне рабочий код:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from random import randint

def matrix_generator(Q, N):
    matrix_list = [[[randint(0, 9)
        for matrix_width in range(N)]
            for matrix_height in range(N)]
                for matrix in range(Q)]
    return matrix_list

def compare_matrix(arrays, symbol='x'):
    result = deepcopy(arrays[0])
    for matrix in arrays:
        for line in range(len(matrix)):
            for elem in range(len(matrix[line])):
                if not result[line][elem] == matrix[line][elem]:
                    result[line][elem] = symbol
    return result

arrays = matrix_generator(3, 3)
## Следующие закомменченные строчки можно удалить, они из idle
# print(arrays)
# >>> [[[2, 1, 0], [7, 7, 4], [6, 9, 6]], [[5, 0, 5], [9, 9, 7], [4, 5, 5]], [[1, 8, 8], [8, 2, 8], [9, 2, 9]]]
## Заменяем каждый [0,0], [1,1], [2,2] на 1, 2, 3
# arrays = [[[1, 1, 0], [7, 2, 4], [6, 9, 3]], [[1, 0, 5], [9, 2, 7], [4, 5, 3]], [[1, 8, 8], [8, 2, 8], [9, 2, 3]]]
compare_matrix(arrays)
# >>> [[1, 'x', 'x'], ['x', 2, 'x'], ['x', 'x', 3]]
```

Comment: место `not a == b` лучше писать `a != b`